# Instantiate from parent class in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, instantiation

### instantiating Objects from parent classes

Hey guys what am i doing wrong?
Basicly i have 3 classes

```
class Person:
"""
An example class to hold a
person name and age """

instance_count = 0

@classmethod
def increment_instance_count(cls):
    cls.instance_count += 1

def __init__(self, name, age):
    Person.increment_instance_count()
    # Person.instance_count += 1
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

def __str__(self):
    return self.name + ' is ' + str(self.age)

def birthday(self):
    print ('Happy birthday you were', self.age)
    self.age += 1
    print('You are now', self.age)

def calculate_pay(self, hours_worked):
    rate_of_pay = 7.50
    if self.age >= 21:
        rate_of_pay += 2.50
    return hours_worked * rate_of_pay

def is_teenager(self):
    return self.age < 20
```

**This is my second class:**

```
class Employee (Person):
def __int__(self, name, age, id):
    super().__init__(name, age)
    self.id = id

def calculate_pay(self, hours_worked):
    rate_of_pay = 7.50
    if self.age >= 21:
        rate_of_pay += 2.50
    return hours_worked * rate_of_pay
```

**This is another childrens class which inherites from both:**

```
class SalesPerson(Employee):
def __init__(self, name, age, id, region, sales):
    super().__init__(name, age, id)
    self.region = region
    self.sales = sales

def bonus(self):
    return self.sales * 0.5
```

Whenever I try to instantiate an object inside one of children's classes like

```
e = Employee('Denise', 51, 7468)
```

or

```
p = Person('John', 54)
```

I get an error that the variable `Employee` or `Person` is undefined.

All of the classfiles are in the same folder.

Comment: Are you actually importing these files that contain your classes?  Merely having them all in the same folder does nothing.

Comment: how do i have to import them? i thought its enough to make a reference in the round bracklets after declaring the class like:

class SubClassName(BaseClassName):
        class -body

Comment: If the classes aren't all defined in the same file, you need to import the module before you can use anything defined in it.

Comment: thank you very much guys, it worked. i thought it was enough to put all the files inside the same folder.